# MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests

Tags: rx-java

I've received a bug report including `MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests` for an RxJava `Flowable`, but I'm struggling to create a simple test case the demonstrates the problem (maintaining the structure of the `Flowable`).

Here's the test I'm trying to put together, which maintains the same stages in the pipeline:

```
int inputEvents=10000;

CountDownLatch completed = new CountDownLatch(1);
Flowable<List<String>> flowable = Flowable.<String>create(e -> {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Will send");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < inputEvents; counter++) {
        e.onNext("" + counter);
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Completed sending");
    e.onComplete();
}, BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
    .onBackpressureDrop(s -> System.out.println("Backpressure, dropping " + Arrays.asList(s)))
    .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnNext(strings -> System.out.println("\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Buffered: " + strings.size() + " items"))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)
    .doOnNext(strings -> {
        System.out.println("\t" + "\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Waiting: " + strings.size());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    });

flowable
    .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("\t" + "\t" + "onNext: " + s.size()),
            error -> {
                throw new RuntimeException(error);
            },
            () -> {
                System.out.println("\t" + "\t" + "Complete");
                completed.countDown();
            });

completed.await();
```

In production, we get `MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests` with the following stack trace:

```
io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.QueueDrainSubscriber.fastPathEmitMax(QueueDrainSubscriber.java:87)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableBufferTimed$BufferExactUnboundedSubscriber.run(FlowableBufferTimed.java:207)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.run(ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So I think this relates to downstream work from the buffer.

However, no matter how long I block in the `doOnNext` I can't reproduce the problem. Example output:

```
main: Will send
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
        RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: Waiting: 197
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 196 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 196 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
        onNext: 197
        RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: Waiting: 196
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 196 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
        onNext: 196
        RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: Waiting: 197
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
    RxComputationThreadPool-1: Buffered: 197 items
...
```

I was expecting, as the `Thread.sleep(5000)` takes so long, we would get back pressure.

Is there a way of simulating this, ideally in a test using TestScheduler/TestSubscriber (to avoid the `Thread.sleep()`s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the MissingBackpressureException by increasing the rate at which your events are emitted, increasing the max number of events, and reducing the rate at which the consumer processes them.

The buffer that's overflowing is the default `observeOn(...)` operator's buffer of size 128. Since it's receiving a new list once a second, it will take at least a couple of minutes of back pressure before it will overflow.

Note, you can override this default buffer size by passing it as an arg to `observeOn(...)`.

Getting back to backpressure handling, I think the main issue with your pipeline is the `buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` operator. If you look at the javadoc:

> Backpressure:This operator does not support backpressure as it uses
>   time. It requests Long.MAX_VALUE upstream and does not obey downstream
>   requests.

As a result of the above your `onBackPressureDrop(...)` never gets invoked. I think you fix this by placing `onBackPressureDrop(...)` after `buffer(...)`. Doing so results in your `Backpressure, dropping...` message.

You should be able to unit test this using:
`TestScheduler.advanceTimeBy(long, TimeUnit)`. Though I have to admit, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I'm confused - there are multiple `Buffered: 197 items` logs which suggest 197 items at a time are being passed to `observeOn` - shouldn't this overflow the buffer in `observeOn` given the downstream actions are taking multiple seconds to occur?

Comment: Another difference I have observed from production to this test is that even though both use `Schedulers.io()`, in production multiple threads are created (128 of them, I guess mimicking the onNexts from the upstream buffer) whereas whenever I run this test only one thread is created.

Comment: @DanGravell, the `observeOn`'s upstream is emitting `List<String>`, so the buffer is really a buffer of 128 `Lists` and not a buffer of the individual `Strings`.

Comment: D'oh - getting my granularities wrong! Thanks, will take another look at this.

Comment: Yeah, just by altering the parameters this can work, I was being too gentle on the code!

Comment: ... and I might be wrong, but I don't think it's possible to use `TestScheduler` here - `TestScheduler` is not concurrent, so passing it as the scheduler to the `observeOn` and `buffer` calls won't allow the buffer overflows to occur.

Comment: @DanGravell Hi Dan, Did u find a way to reproduce this error? May you share the code? BTW, do you know how to get current buffer size in the consumer of flowable.

Comment: Oh I reproduce it too by settting buffer size. And @TrogDor 's strategy which mention place onBackPressureDrop after sample is useful. Thanks you guys very much! I think our product's bug could be fixed.