# Understanding the capacity param in RxJava onBackpressureBuffer

Tags: android, rx-java, backpressure

Here is a small sample app that I wrote:

```
package ru.maksim.sample.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.BackpressureOverflowStrategy
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.BackpressureStrategy
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        disposable = observeInts()
            .subscribe(
                {
                    Log.d("SampleApp", "next=$it")
                },
                {
                    Log.e("SampleApp", "error", it)
                },
                {
                    Log.d("SampleApp", "complete")
                }
            )
        start.setOnClickListener {
            subject.onNext(1)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        disposable.dispose()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun observeInts() = subject
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .onBackpressureBuffer(4, {
            Log.d("SampleApp", "Overflow")
        }, BackpressureOverflowStrategy.DROP_LATEST)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .flatMap {
            Log.d("SampleApp", "onNext BEFORE delay: $it")
            Flowable.just(it)
        }
        .delay(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap {
            Log.d("SampleApp", "onNext AFTER delay: $it")
            Flowable.just(it)
        }
}
```

`start` is just a button. After pressing the button more than 4 (4 is the buffer capacity as you can see in `onBackpressureBuffer`) times, I expected to see `Overflow` is logs, but it didn't happen. I don't understand why.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756850/missingbackpressureexception-could-not-emit-buffer-due-to-lack-of-requests

Comment: The above referenced question is difficult to find, I've submitted an edit to update its description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)). Namely,

```
onBackpressureBuffer(int capacity)
```

This is a bounded version that signals BufferOverflowErrorin case its buffer reaches the given capacity.

```
Flowable.range(1, 1_000_000)
          .onBackpressureBuffer(16)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .subscribe(e -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

The relevance of this operator is decreasing as more and more operators now allow setting their buffer sizes. For the rest, this gives an opportunity to "extend their internal buffer" by having a larger number with onBackpressureBuffer than their default.

---

It looks like in addition to `16` passed to `onBackpressureBuffer` other operators have their own buffers. And when the 17-th item is received, the preceding 16 might be buffered in different operators' buffers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you hadn't seen a warning, because there were very few events.
You can try to replace your callback in setOnClickListener on this and check it again:

```
start.setOnClickListener {
    for (i in 0..1000) {
        subject.onNext(i)
    }   
}
```

Also you can change line with method "observeOn" to:

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1)
```

Because the scheduler has his buffer too.